# K3b can't burn Blu ray disc. Mkisofs crashes

Tags: kubuntu, crash, k3b

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and i have a problem burning a blu ray disc. Everytime i try, i get a message that mkisofs crashed. I followed everything as explained here (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306962), but it still doesn't burn.
Please help.

Debuging output:

*

```
*Burned media
----------------------- BD-R Sequential (SRM) Devices
----------------------- HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BH10LS30 1.00 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, BD-ROM, BD-R, BD-RE, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW, BD-ROM, BD-R Sequential (SRM), BD-R Random (RRM), BD-RE] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump, Random Recording, Sequential Recording, Sequential Recording + POW] [%7] K3b::IsoImager
----------------------- mkisofs print size result: 11239004 (23017480192 bytes) System
----------------------- K3b Version: 19.12.3 KDE Version: 5.67.0 Qt Version:  5.12.8 Kernel:      5.4.0-60-generic Used versions
----------------------- mkisofs: 1.1.11 growisofs: 7.1 growisofs
----------------------- Executing 'builtin_dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0' /dev/sr0: pre-formatting blank BD-R for 24.8GB... /dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 8.2x4390KBps.    38600704/23017480192 ( 0.2%) @1.9x, remaining 59:31 RBU 100.0% UBU 
50.0%    52822016/23017480192 ( 0.2%) @0.9x, remaining 72:27 RBU 100.0% UBU  50.0% :-[ WRITE@LBA=64c0h failed with SK=5h/ASC=21h/ACQ=04h]: Invalid argument :-( write failed: Invalid argument /dev/sr0: flushing cache :-[ FLUSH CACHE failed with SK=2h/LOGICAL UNIT IS IN PROCESS OF BECOMING READY]: Resource temporarily unavailable :-[ SYNCHRONOUS FLUSH CACHE failed with SK=2h/LOGICAL UNIT IS IN PROCESS OF BECOMING READY]: Resource temporarily unavailable growisofs command:
----------------------- /usr/bin/growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/dev/fd/0 -use-the-force-luke=notray -use-the-force-luke=tty -use-the-force-luke=4gms -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:11239004 -dvd-compat -speed=8 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m mkisofs
----------------------- Warning: creating filesystem that does not conform to ISO-9660. 11239004 Warning: creating filesystem that does not conform to ISO-9660. Warning: ISO-9660 filenames longer than 31 may cause buffer overflows in the OS.
  0.00% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
  0.01% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.02% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.03% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.04% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 3 times. ===
  0.05% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.06% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.07% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.08% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 3 times. ===
  0.09% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.10% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.11% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.12% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 3 times. ===
  0.13% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.14% done, estimate finish Sun Jan 10 22:42:55 2021
=== last message repeated 2 times. ===
  0.15% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 02:07:06 2021
  0.15% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 02:01:09 2021
  0.16% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 02:06:14 2021
  0.16% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 02:00:38 2021
  0.16% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:55:10 2021
  0.17% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:50:09 2021
  0.17% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:45:24 2021
  0.18% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:40:44 2021
  0.18% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:45:34 2021
  0.19% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:41:15 2021
  0.19% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:37:08 2021
  0.20% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:33:05 2021
  0.20% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:29:24 2021
  0.20% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:25:42 2021
  0.21% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:30:14 2021
  0.21% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:26:46 2021
  0.22% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:23:27 2021
  0.22% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:20:10 2021
  0.23% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:17:10 2021
  0.23% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:14:08 2021
  0.24% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:11:18 2021
  0.24% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:08:35 2021
  0.24% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:12:46 2021
  0.25% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:10:01 2021
  0.25% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:07:27 2021
  0.26% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:04:58 2021
  0.26% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:02:35 2021
  0.27% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 01:00:16 2021
  0.27% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:57:58 2021
  0.28% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:55:49 2021
  0.28% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:53:44 2021
  0.28% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:57:29 2021
  0.29% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:55:26 2021
  0.29% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:53:27 2021
  0.30% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:51:29 2021
  0.30% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:49:36 2021
  0.31% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:47:47 2021
  0.31% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:45:58 2021
  0.32% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:44:14 2021
  0.32% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:42:34 2021
  0.32% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:46:02 2021
  0.33% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:44:23 2021
  0.33% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:42:47 2021
  0.34% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:41:10 2021
  0.34% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:39:39 2021
  0.35% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:38:10 2021
  0.35% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:36:43 2021
  0.36% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:35:18 2021
  0.36% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:38:30 2021
  0.36% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:37:06 2021
  0.37% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:35:44 2021
  0.37% done, estimate finish Mon Jan 11 00:34:23 2021 mkisofs calculate size command:
----------------------- /usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -print-size -quiet -volid E_2020_06_bis_10 -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2018 SEBASTIAN TRUEG, MICHAL MALEK AND LESLIE ZHAI
-publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/k3b.cUqKWa -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/k3b.ZesVwo -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/k3b.vydLGT -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -allow-lowercase -no-iso-translate -max-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/k3b.fXWitO mkisofs command:
----------------------- /usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -volid E_2020_06_bis_10 -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2018 SEBASTIAN TRUEG, MICHAL MALEK AND LESLIE ZHAI -publisher  -preparer 
-sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/k3b.OPWNCk -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/k3b.LoGTMr -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/k3b.PHjcVC -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -allow-lowercase -no-iso-translate -max-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/k3b.MuYXwv*
```

- 

Answer (score 2):

We are facing the same challenge here. Using KDE on Debian 10 Buster. When burning BD-R, K3b display this error message **mkisof crashed**

This is how we resolved this challenge. First, set the appropriate permissions on 3 files: "/usr/bin/**wodim**", "/usr/bin/**cdrdao**", "/usr/bin/**growisofs**". Second, use good quality BD-R. Third, do not add more than **23,609 MB** per BD-R. Fourth, use the K3b **Growisofs** writing app.

---

Below is the same resolution as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

**Step 1: Permissions**

1. Close K3b
2. If not already done, add your Linux user to the permission group **cdrom**
3. Using Terminal/Console as any user with the Sudo permission, execute those 3 command lines to set the appropriate permissions on 3 files:

   1. `sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/wodim`
   2. `sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/cdrdao`
   3. `sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/growisofs`
4. If somehow the above is not working. At step 3 above, if appropriate for your device, try permission **4775** instead of 4711. Then restart your device. Then try again to burn a BD-R.
5. Next, you need to get good quality disc below.

---

**Step 2: Quality Disc**

1. Use good quality BD-R. Such as **Verbatim**. They are made in Japan and very reliable. In comparison, cheaper products often failed. In turn, in the long run, the cheaper quality products end up being more expensive. Because a significant amount of discs failed, and the time wasted re-burning disc.
2. After this, you need to remind within the limited capacity of BD-R below.

**Step 3: Max 23,609 MB**

1. When you use K3b and add files to your project. Do not add more than **23,609 MB**. The challenge with K3b is that, when burning BD-R, K3b will let you add more than 23,609 MB. But K3b will not warn you that this exceeds the capacity of BD-R. In turn, when burning, the error mkisof crashed is display :( Then it failed. To resolve this challenge, you need to double-check that you do not exceed 23,609 MB. Assuming that you use Verbatim disc. Other disc might have a different limit.
2. Using K3b, at the bottom, use it's "**Available**" row to double-check that you do not exceed 23,609 MB
3. After this, you need to use K3b with the writing app Growisofs below.

**Step 4: Growisofs**

1. Configure K3b to use Growisofs writing app to burn BD-R. By default, K3b automatically uses Growisofs to burn BD-R. If somehow Growisofs is not automatically selected, this can be resolved by manually selecting Growisofs. To do so, using K3b, navigate to "**Configuration**" menu ---> "**Settings**". Under "**Burning**" group, check this option "**Show advanced GUI elements**".
   [image]
2. Using the "**Data Project**" window, the new "**Writing app**" menu will be display. Choose either the "**Growisofs**" option, or the "**Auto**" option. If unsure, choose "**Growisofs**" option.
   [image]
3. Burn. Done. Enjoy :)

---

**Attribution**

Thanks to phd21, dave8671, and Michael Harvey for their contribution about this resolution at https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=153&t=118981&p=447942#